# jQuery and Safari 4.0.1 - ToggleClass effect

Tags: jquery-ui, safari

I am currently developing a webpage where I want to use the ToggleClass function from jQuery. I went on to the jQuery UI website, as I think this is an extension of the original jQuery.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

When I click the 'Run Effect' button, nothing happens. Is it just my browser or slow computer or do any of you also get this in Safari <del>4.0.1</del> 4.0 (4530.17)?

I tested in Firefox 3.0.10 and it worked, so by the looks of it, jQuery UI is not all that compatible with Safari <del>4.0.1</del> 4.0 (4530.17), or just maybe their demos on their site?

Anyone care to elaborate?

Edit: sorry, was under the impression that I had 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows: Safari 4.0 (530.17): Fail

That being the case, .animate() still appears to work. If your transformation isn't too complicated, you could use that as your alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I knew it was my code b/c the example page at the reference you provided above worked just fine.

Check your .css. For some reason, the css

> 'a.filterOn:link, a.filterOn:visited{
>     background: green;
>   }'

wouldn't work in Safari, but worked just fine in FF. However, b/c these were nested inside of another element, I tried:

> '#filters a.filterOn:link, #filters a.filterOn:visited{
>     background: green;
>   }'

which for some reason worked. My guess is that, if you haven't solved it yet, the problem is in the .css, not the jquery.